# Foreign Key with multiple Inherited Classes EF Core 2.0 Code First

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api, ef-core-2.0

I have 2 classes (**A & B**), both inherit from my **Base** class.
My **Side** Class has a **BaseId** and a **Base** field.

I'm working with Code First and Table per Concrete Class (TPC)

I'm trying to create Foreign keys to connect the **Side** table with my **A & B** table. When i create only one relation with fluent api it works fine. But when i add the second one, the new migration drop the FKs from **A** and create a new one for **B**. Why i can't create 2 relations?

```
public class Base
{
    public int    Id   { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class A : Base
{
    public string StringA { get; set; }
}

public class B : Base
{
    public string StringA { get; set; }
}

public class Side
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BaseId { get; set; }
    public Base Base { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Side>().HasOne(s => (A) s.Base);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Side>().HasOne(s => (B) s.Base);
}
```

Comment: There is no TPC support in EF Core yet, so I don't see how this could work at all. And of course you cannot use **one** FK to reference **two** different tables - this is basic rdbms principle.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you already got this figured out, but as previously mentioned table TPC isn't supported!  You can use TPH.

To do TPH just do the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Side>.ToTable("Sides")
            .HasDiscriminator<SideType>("SideType")
            .HasValue<A>(SideType.BASE_A)
            .HasValue<B>(SideType.BASE_A);



 public enum SideType {
    BASE_A = 100,
    BASE_B = 500
 }
```